# CSSの変更や追加は可能ですか？

Tags: 機能の要求, デザイン

ユーザーコミュニティ側から依頼した場合、スタック・オーバーフロー（日本語版 StackOverflow）のスタイル指定（CSS）を変更、あるいは追加することは可能ですか？ 不具合の修正であれば、当然対応していただけると思うのですが、それ以上の依頼を想定しています。

どのような依頼が有り得るかというと、

- 日本語に配慮したフォント指定
- 英語版と区別可能なアクセントカラー

などが考えられます。今現在、要望がまとまっているわけでは有りません。

---

関連: [CSSで和文フォントを指定してほしい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1561/3054) （この質問は「完了」になっていますが、結末は良く分かりません）

Comment: ネイティブじゃない人には気づかない箇所も多々あるので、(最終的には) 要望が具体的だと通りやすくなるかも。 / サイトによってアクセントカラーは結構違いますし、バナー画像が表示されるサイトもあるので (例: https://academia.stackexchange.com ) 、「ここは日本語版だ」とアピールできると良いかもしれないですね。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

上記の cubick さんのコメントがおそらく最も正しく、リクエストがどれくらい具体的であるかによります。現在の日本語フォントが明確ではないという場合、あなた (コミュニティ) が推奨するスタック用の今とは別のフォントを特定してくだされば、ここメタでリクエストが可能であり、そこからモデレーションチームが依頼をエスカレートする流れになります。

その場合、どのフォントなのか、フォント数は一つなのか二つかという詳細が必要となります。

アクセントカラーについては、 CM の 1 人がブランディングチームに連絡し、そこでどのような変更が許可されるのか判断されます。Stack Overflow 以外のサイトであればカスタマイズされたテーマを取得することがありますが、Stack Overflow ブランドについては私たちは非常に慎重であるため、サイトのデザインの変更についてはここで約束できません。

とはいえ、皆さんがどのような具体的な変更を望んでいるかがわかるまで「ノー」とは言いたくありません。リンクの色のような小さなものであれば、大々的な変更よりも考慮される可能性が高くなります。

申し訳ありませんが、これ以上シンプルな回答を書けません。具体的な質問でなければその答えを知ることができません。